# Partitioning MySQL vs PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, partitioning

For our new system we are looking for database server. We considered a lot of pros/cons for MySQL(InnoDB) vs PostgreSQL and the breaking point for us is partitioning. We will choose the one which partitioning fits better our needs.

#### Our case

The IS is backend for selling tickets. We sell thousands of tickets daily so the table scales quite fast and seat reservations scale even faster.

```
+--------------+            +-------------------+
| tickets      |    1:N     | seat_reservations |
+--------------+            +-------------------+
```

We want to use date partitioning for both of these tables and some others but this is the core.

We need to force preserve db integrity via foreign keys or some similar solution. I know that InnoDB doesn't support FK with partitioning.

#### The questions

- Does PostgreSQL support FK and Partitioning? Probably for rules based partitioning.
- Is another way how to force preserve DB integrity?
- Which SQL server do you recomend? (based on partitioning)

I plan to partition both tables. I want partition even more than that (log,...) but these are the main tables.

We are just building the system so we want to use the newest versions; MySQL 5.6 or PostgreSQL 9.3. The r/w ratio will be about 3:1 (r:w), and the line count will be 700k growing about 100k per month so we have to be able to have more than 7m lines.

Comment: "want to use date partitioning" -- Why?  There is no automatic performance advantage.  Let's see the queries that might benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, PostgreSQL does not directly support foreign keys and partitions. You can create a foreign key on each partition, but there is no way to have a foreign key against a set of partitions without either coding the constraint triggers yourself or using a key management table.

There are several ways to resolve this, but they require some understanding of underlying db implementation concepts to make perform well.

The first is to do your referential integrity enforcement manually through triggers.  You can write constraint triggers which can be deferred (if needed) that check the existence of foreign key information.  Note this is subject to `ALTER TABLE DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` issues but it should generally work.

The second is to have a separate table which stores keys and is maintained through a combination of triggers and bulk data operations.  This can help a great deal.

So it is possible to enforce things but it requires a bit more work.

I don't know enough about MySQL's table partitioning capabilities to comment on it though.